# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ']' in C:\xampp\htdocs\eazyR\eazy\sites\erp\ajaxify\excel.php on line 37

Tags: php, html, excel, export-to-excel

Please help... am working on a form within as html page that export my SQL table to excel and download it. but i have been experience error

**Anythime i click the Export to excel button it keep taking me to a new page instead of export data to excel.** 
Below is my form and the excel.php script

Form

```
<form method="post" action="sites/erp/ajaxify/excel.php">
    <div id="content">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 text-center">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button id="exportbtn" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block">  Export to Excel </button>
                </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**and the Excel.php**

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['tablename']) && isset($_REQUEST['keyy'])){
$tablename = use_if_sent('tablename');
$result = $ez_db->query("SELECT `firstname`, 'lastname', 'email', 'gender', 'user_group', 'phone', status' FROM 'signup'");
 if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
        $output .= '
        <table class="table" bordered="1">  
            <tr>  
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Lastname</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Gender</th>
                <th>Department</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
                <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
        ';
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
           $output .= '
            <tr>  
                <td>'.$row["firstname".'</td>  
                <td>'.$row["lastname"].'</td>  
                <td>'.$row["email"].'</td>  
                <td>'.$row["gender"].'</td>  
                <td>'.$row["user_group"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["phone"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["status"].'</td>
            </tr>
           ';
        }
      $output .= '</table>';
      header('Content-Type: application/xls');
      header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=download.xls');
      echo $output;
    }  
}
?>
```

Comment: `<td>'.$row["firstname".'</td>` - now what’s missing here, eagle-eye …?

Comment: please i dont get

Comment: please correct it this code:   <td>'.$row["firstname".'</td>   to this   <td>'.$row["firstname"].'</td>

Comment: Compare that line with the next line, `<td>'.$row["lastname"].'</td>` - now what is the structural difference here? And keep in mind, that the error message already told you it was expecting a `]` somewhere, but didn’t find it …

Comment: Thanks i did that and its now opening a blank page.

Comment: This can hardly be your whole script, because in PHP there is no built-in function named `use_if_sent`.

Comment: Please have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-back-ticks-in-mysql

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please correct it this code:

```
<td>'.$row["firstname".'</td>
```

To this :

```
<td>'.$row["firstname"].'</td>
```

Comment: Thanks i did that and its now opening a blank page.

Comment: So please first check whether your $result contain values or not.

Comment: How do i do that sir?

Answer (score -1):

In Excel.php

```
<td>'.$row["firstname".'</td>
```

should change as

```
<td>'.$row["firstname"].'</td>
```

You missed to close the square brace ].

And you are not doing excel export here. You are setting Content Type to application\xls to html content. This will not export excel.

See [Excel export tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/generate-excel-files-charts-phpexcel/) to get an idea of excel export.

Change your html code to this.

```
    <form method="post" action="sites/erp/ajaxify/excel.php" target="exportExcelFrame">
    <div id="content">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 text-center">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button id="exportbtn" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block">  Export to Excel </button>
                </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<iframe style="display:none;" id="exportExcelFrame" name="exportExcelFrame"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks i did that and its now opening a blank page.

Comment: becuase You are setting Respone Content Type to application/xls. Set Content Type to text/plain

Comment: i did but am still getting same response , i changed to 
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

Comment: remove this two lines header('Content-Type: application/xls');
      header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=download.xls');

Comment: This will give you html output.  Got to https://www.sitepoint.com/generate-excel-files-charts-phpexcel/ and this page will show you how to export to excel.

Comment: line remove and am still been redirected to http://localhost/eazyR/eazy/sites/erp/ajaxify/excel.php

Comment: set button type to button. <button id="exportbtn" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" type="button">  Export to Excel </button>.

Comment: This will not redirect. But you must first update Excel.php to generate excel file. Currently it seems not. I will update the answer.